# local vmware takes lot of time to pull the docker image from AWS ECR

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, vmware, amazon-ecr

Recently I moved my registry from Dockerhub to AWS ECR.

I'm using Jenkins to pull image and deploy to local vmware. I'm using docker swarm as container orchestration tool.When I was using Dockerhub jenkins was able to pull and deploy docker services successfully.But when I'm using AWS ECR,the jenkins job is UNSTABLE.

Jenkins job is getting timeout.When i checked in server,some images are successfully pulled but some are not.

docker pull image is taking more time when we are using aws ecr.Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue. Because of network slowness jenkins got timed out.

So I removed the time out limit from jenkins then it worked fine.

> 1. Goto Post-build Actions
> 2. Open Advanced
> 3. Exec timeout (ms) : 0

Save and rebuild the job

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to many reasons.

1. Network/firewall issues.
2. Storage volume slowness etc.

I think first you need to narrow down the issue. Did you check the latency between the Jenkins worker and AWS ECR? I would suggest directly login into the Jenkins worker and try pulling the Image directly. If the direct pulling is working without a slowness you may have to dig into Jenkins to understand what's happening.

Comment: I have pulled the image from AWS ECR to jenkins worker.Direct pulling is really slow.

Comment: I really want to know why this is happening with AWS ECR,For Docker hub it is working fine.